# File IO, Handling CRLF

Tags: c++, c

I am writing a program that takes a file and splits it up into multiple small files of a user specified size, then join the multiple small files back again.

1. the code must work for C and C++
2. I am compiling with multiple compilers.
3. I am reading and writing to the files by using the functions `fread()` and `fwrite()`
4. `fread()` and `fwrite()` handle bytes, not strings.

The problem I am having pertains to CRLF. If the file I am reading from contains CRLF, then I want to retain it when i split and join the files back together. If the file contains LF, then i want to retain LF.

Unfortunately, `fread()` seems to store CRLF as `\n` (I think), and whatever is written by `fwrite()` is compiler-dependent.

How do I approach this problem?

Comment: `fread` and `fwrite` are standard C functions (they are declared in the `cstdio` header), not STL.

Comment: Note: Opening the file in text mode will cause the file function to translate the platform specific EOL sequence into '\n'. If you open the file in binary mode then no translation occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    FILE * f = fopen( "file.txt", "rb" );
    char c;
    while( fread( &c, 1, 1, f ) ) {
        if ( c == '\r' ) {
            printf( "CR\n" );
        }
        else if ( c == '\n' ) {
            printf( "LF\n" );
        }
        else {
            printf( "%c\n" , c );
        }
    }
    fclose( f );
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Do the read/write in binary mode. That should make it irrelevant whether there are CRLF or LF line endings.

Comment: I am doing read/write in binary. fread and fwrite work in binary.

Comment: @aCuria Are you fopen("file.txt","rb")/fopen("file.txt","wb")?

Comment: @aCuria You need to open the file in binary mode.

Comment: Just to clarify, did you open the file in binary mode?  pFile = fopen ( "myfile.txt" , "wb+" );

Comment: Thanks Artyom, Neil This is exactly the problem. +1